# Función para obtener un listado de directorios

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Quiero crear una función que me devuelva una lista de directorios como una `array` dentro de esta base de código:

```
public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio, string filtro)
{
    string[] devolver = null;
    listFicheros = devolver;
    return devolver;
}
```

El problema que se me presenta es que no sé que funciones/librerías debo usar.

Comment: Xabier, edita tu pregunta y se mas explicito con lo que quieres e incluye un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la libreria de [System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx) con las funciones de [Directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) puedes obtener lo que buscas:

```
public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio, string filtro)
{
    string[] devolver = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directorio, filtro);

    return devolver;
}
```

Puedes simplificar más las líneas de código poniendo el código de la siguiente forma:

```
public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio, string filtro)
{
    return System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(directorio, filtro);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a intentarlo de esa manera

Comment: Vale creo que tengo la función mas o menos, ahora como la puedo llamar desde un botón de otra clase?  Para meterla en este botón                                                private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               }

Comment: Depende de dónde hayas puesto esta función, la llamarias como: `nombreClase.obtenerListadoDirectorio(directorio,filtro);`

Siempre que tengas instanciada `nombreClase`.

Comment: vlae esta es la funcion finalmente. Ahora como la llamo desde el button?                                                    
 public string[] obtenerListadoDirectorio(string directorio, string filtro)
        {       

            string[] devolver = null;

            string[] listFicheros = null;
            

              FileInfo[] infFile = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directorio).GetFiles("*.txt");
              listFicheros = infFile.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();

            listFicheros = devolver;
            return devolver;

        }

Comment: Si quieres buscar en subdirectorios tienes que agregar un tercer parámetro a la función GetDirectories. Por lo demás todo bien